# Parsing JSON using GSON in java and populating a list view

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I realize my questions have been asked a lot but I have spent a considerable amount of time scouring both SO and google trying to get a better understanding of this concept with no success.  I've seen many different implementations, which is what leads me to get some advice about my specific situation.

**MY OBJECTIVE**

I need to perform a post request to a php file and the goal is to ultimately populate fields in a list activity with some of the json data.

**HTTP POST RESPONSE**

Here is the format of the response data I'm getting back from the server, which appears to be a JSON object of arrays(?).

```
   {"expense":[{"cat_id_PK":237,"cat_name":"Name1","cat_amount":"100.00","is_recurring":0},
   {"cat_id_PK":238,"cat_name":"Name2","cat_amount":"200.00","is_recurring":0},
   {"cat_id_PK":239,"cat_name":"Name3","cat_amount":"300.00","is_recurring":0},
   {"cat_id_PK":240,"cat_name":"Name4","cat_amount":"400.00","is_recurring":0}],
   "expense_rec": [{"cat_id_PK":207,"cat_name":"Name5","cat_amount":"500.00","is_recurring":1}]}
```

**FIRST QUESTION**

The code below is what I'm using to read the response.  Is this how I should be handling that?  It seems weird to get a json encoded response and then change it to a string, only to try and access elements of a json object again.  Am I on the wrong track here?

```
//This code is in the doInBackground method of my "sendPostRequest" async task.
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String bufferedStrChunk = null;

while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
      stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
}
//Returns string to onPostExecute()
return stringBuilder.toString();
```

**SECOND QUESTION**

I have another file called "PostResponse.java" that holds the following code I modeled after a tutorial online.  I'm unsure of how to interact with this class from the onPostExecute method. How can I access say, the first item in the first object (something like in PHP where you could do: expense[0]['cat_name']).  I've tried to do this various ways with no success. Here is the PostResponse.java class:

```
public class PostResponse {
public Integer cat_id_PK;
public String cat_name;
public BigDecimal cat_amount;
public Integer is_recurring;

public int getID() {
    return this.cat_id_PK;
}
public void setID(int cat_id_PK){
    this.cat_id_PK = cat_id_PK;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.cat_name;
}
public void setName(String cat_name) {
    this.cat_name = cat_name;
}

public BigDecimal getAmount() {
    return this.cat_amount;
}
public void setAmount(BigDecimal cat_amount) {
    this.cat_amount = cat_amount;
}

public int getRecurring() {
    return this.is_recurring;
}
public void setRecurring(int is_recurring) {
    this.is_recurring = is_recurring;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("*** Categories ***");
    sb.append("cat_id_PK="+getID()+"\n");
    sb.append("cat_name="+getName()+"\n");
    sb.append("cat_amount="+getAmount()+"\n");
    sb.append("is_recurring="+getRecurring()+"\n");

    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

and here is the content of my onPostExecute method:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    Gson gson = new Gson();              
    PostResponse response = gson.fromJson(result, PostResponse.class);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Like I said originally, my ultimate goal is to populate these items to a list activity, but at this point I'd settle for just knowing how to get at specific elements.  However, if anyone would like to include how to populate a list activity in their response, it would save me a lot more headaches, as nothing with java is coming easy for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **FIRST QUESTION**
>
> The code below is what I'm using to read the response. Is this how I should be handling that? It seems weird to get a json encoded response and then change it to a string, only to try and access elements of a json object again. Am I on the wrong track here?

It's one way of handling the http response. A "json encoded response" is little more than a text-based response, so converting it into a string on the receiving end would make sense. That is, the json you receive isn't an 'object' as far as Java is concerned: it's just textual representation of an object (or a bunch of objects in your case), received as a stream of bytes.

That being said, you can potentially shorten your code by skipping the string(builder) part. Gson provides an [alternative constructor that takes a `Reader`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.io.Reader-java.lang.Class-) instance, for which you can suppy the `BufferedReader` in your code snippet.

As a side note: the conversion of textual json into Java objects is a potentially 'heavy' operation. As such, you'd best avoid doing it on the main/ui thread, so just move it into the `doInBackground()`  method of your `AsyncTask` (and change types appropriately).

> **SECOND QUESTION**
>
> I have another file called "PostResponse.java" that holds the following code I modeled after a tutorial online. I'm unsure of how to interact with this class from the onPostExecute method. How can I access say, the first item in the first object (something like in PHP where you could do: expense[0]['cat_name']). I've tried to do this various ways with no success.

You're close, but if you look more closely to the json sample, you'll see that your `PostResponse` class is not a good match for it:

```
{
  "expense": [
    {
      "cat_id_PK": 237,
      "cat_name": "Name1",
      "cat_amount": "100.00",
      "is_recurring": 0
    },
    {
      "cat_id_PK": 238,
      "cat_name": "Name2",
      "cat_amount": "200.00",
      "is_recurring": 0
    },
    {
      "cat_id_PK": 239,
      "cat_name": "Name3",
      "cat_amount": "300.00",
      "is_recurring": 0
    },
    {
      "cat_id_PK": 240,
      "cat_name": "Name4",
      "cat_amount": "400.00",
      "is_recurring": 0
    }
  ],
  "expense_rec": [
    {
      "cat_id_PK": 207,
      "cat_name": "Name5",
      "cat_amount": "500.00",
      "is_recurring": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Consider the more hierarchical formatting above. On the first level there are two (json) objects: `expense` and `expense_rec` (both contain 0...* elements, as the square brackets indicate). That means that whatever class you're going to be trying to map the json onto, should define these fields too. If you now look at your `PostResponse` class, it should become obvious that in its current form it in fact models one of the child objects of the aforementioned fields.

Basically, the classes to map the json onto, should look somewhat like this:

PostResponse:

```
public class PostResponse {

    public ExpenseItem[] expense;
    public ExpenseItem[] expense_rec; 
    // List<ExpenseItem> is also supported

    // getters & setters
}
```

ExpenseItem:

```
public class ExpenseItem {

    public Integer cat_id_PK;
    public String cat_name;
    public BigDecimal cat_amount;
    public Integer is_recurring;

    // getters & setters
}
```

With the model classes defined, try to let Gson work its magic again. If all goes well, you should be able to access the data in a way similar to what you're used to in PHP:

```
// map json to POJOs
PostResponse response = new Gson().fromJson(bufferedReader, PostResponse.class);
// retrieve the cat_name for the first item (assuming there is one)
String catName = response.getExpense()[0].getName();
```

... or any of the other fields through the getters defined in `ExpenseItem`.

Once you have this part working, it's going to be fairly straightforward to supply the array or list of expenses to an adapter (have a look at `ArrayAdapter` in the Android framenwork) and bind that adapter to a `ListView`.

Comment: I implemented your suggestions, but now I'm getting an error:  "Expected String but was BEGIN_OBJECT".  I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that my asynctask is expecting a string and returns a string, also my doInBackground method expects a string and returns a string to my onPostExecute which also expects a string.  I've used arrays in my POJOs and used PostResponse response = new Gson().fromJson(bufferedReader, PostResponse.class);

Comment: BTW - your suggestions have been super helpful, so thank you!

Comment: @hyphen: the error you're describing is normally the result of trying to map a complex json object (something inbetween `{...}`) onto a java string. Think of it as a type mismatch, where the Java objects don't model the json correctly. Basically, anything inbetween `{...}` should have an equivalent object in Java. Have a look around on SO and you'll find lots of similar issues and their solutions. If that doesn't help, perhaps consider updating the question with your progress so that we can continue from there.

Answer (score 1):

1. The answer is yes, you will get the response in InputStream
2. For your second question check this out - [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) this can be helpful while creating models for your JSON data.

Then to use GSON

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
YourObj yourObj = (YourObj) gson.fromJson(result, YourObj.class);
```

Comment: The jsonschema2pojo website was really helpful.  I don't have enough rep to upvote you, but you get +1 good karma points.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. The answer is yes.Response is received as `InputSteam`
2. protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
   {
       super.onPostExecute(result);

   ```
   Gson gson = new Gson();              
   PostResponse response = gson.fromJson(result, PostResponse.class);
   System.out.println(result);
   ```

   }

This code section mostly means that after an `AsyncTask` that get web Response and get the String format json response,this `onPostExecute` will be called with that Stringfied json.

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
```

Gson is a library supported by Google for android to deserialization into your class OBject.

```
gson.fromJson(result, PostResponse.class);
```

This method is the real process of deserialization. `result` is Stringfied json and the second is the Target class you want to deserialize into.
This will return a PostResponse Object and you can use it now.

Comment: Ok, it seems like I've already done the last line of code you mentioned when I assigned it to the "response" variable, but you're saying I need to do that again?  Also, how would I access just one of the elements in one of the objects?  so If I wanted just a single "cat_name", how would I access that?

Comment: use JsonObject class.  JSONObject json=new JSONObject(string); if you want to access the specified name property,just call json.getString("propertyName")

Answer (score 0):

For the json data (

```
{"expense":[{"cat_id_PK":237,"cat_name":"Name1","cat_amount":"100.00","is_recurring":0},
   {"cat_id_PK":238,"cat_name":"Name2","cat_amount":"200.00","is_recurring":0},
   {"cat_id_PK":239,"cat_name":"Name3","cat_amount":"300.00","is_recurring":0},
   {"cat_id_PK":240,"cat_name":"Name4","cat_amount":"400.00","is_recurring":0}],
   "expense_rec": [{"cat_id_PK":207,"cat_name":"Name5","cat_amount":"500.00","is_recurring":1}]}),
```

it contains two different arrays here, one is "expense" and another is "expense_rec". So if you want to populate these items to a list activity, you can try the follow methods.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
    Log.i(TAG, "jsonObject is : " + jsonObject.toString());

    //this is the first array data 
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("expense");
    Log.i(TAG, "Array length is: " + jsonArray.length());

    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jsoObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = jsoObj.getString("cat_name");
        Log.i(TAG, "file name is: " + name);
    }

    //this is the second array data 
    jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("expense_rec");
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jsoObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = jsoObj.getString("cat_name");
        Log.i(TAG, "file name is: " + name);
    }
}
```